# Calling activity.finish() results in blank screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity `MyActivity.kt` in `MyExampleApp` which can be started by an intent. In the `MyActivity.onCreate()` method I check that the intent contains an extra, and if it does not I finish the activity:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {         
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)         
    if(!intent.hasExtra("MyExtra")) {            
         finish()         
    } else {         
         // some other code 
    } 
  }
```

I noticed a strange behaviour happening the first time `MyActivity` is started via an intent after it has been killed by the system (reproducing this with `adb shell am kill`):
When I fire an intent without the extra from another app (`MyOtherApp`) to open `MyActivity` I get a blank screen and I am unable to navigate back. I checked that `MyActivity` is properly destroyed and `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` tells me that the top activity is the one belonging to `MyOtherApp`.

This only happens when `MyActivity` is **started after it has been killed**. I have been able to consistently reproduce this using `adb shell am kill`. After the first blank screen, if `MyOtherApp` tries to start `MyActivity`, everything works as expected - `MyActivity` is finished before `onCreate()` concludes and I can see `MyOtherApp`.

What could be the cause of the blank screen and why does this only happen after `MyExampleApp` has been killed?

Thanks!